# How can I make a fractional bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I do this:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=variable, fill=value))+geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

I get this

[image]

But I want something like this, basically the values should be colored by fraction. How can I do this? The idea is to basically see the relative contribution of `models, percentiles, and models:percentiles` for each of `R2, R5, and R10`.

[image: Example plot]

dataframe

```
structure(list(term = c("models", "percentiles", "models:percentiles", 
"models", "percentiles", "models:percentiles", "models", "percentiles", 
"models:percentiles"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("R2", "R5", "R10"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0.435697205847009, 0.533615307749147, 0.0306874864038442, 
    0.441369621882273, 0.520198994695284, 0.0384313834224421, 
    0.394491546635206, 0.579421546902868, 0.0260869064619254)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_col` does the job here:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = term)) + geom_col()
```

or

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = term)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]